# ¿Cómo puedo instalar una apk firmada a través de la web?

Tags: android, android-studio, instalacion

he modificado una app y he compilado 3 veces una app en modo Release con las variantes de firma: v1 , v2 y ambas pero en ningún caso puedo instalar la app directamente , me aparece el mensaje:

**Tu teléfono y tus datos personales son más vulnerables a los ataques........**

Le doy a ACEPTAR, pone instalando pero al momento aparece  Aplicación no instalada con el símbolo de exclamación.

Es un móvil con Google Protect desactivado y sin usuario logueado en Google ya la tenía app instalada pero no se instala la nueva versión.

He probado en otro móvil con usuario de Google pero sigue sin instalarse.

No entiendo porqué no me deja instalar la app si la firmo en modo release. Necesito que se pueda instalar y así que se actualice la versión antigua descargándosela de un sitio web en concreto.

¿Alguna idea?

---

La anterior versión era de otro programador. La `versionCode` en teoría no la he cambiado. La `versionName` si. Con el mismo certificado no porque he creado el diccionario de keys, Lo extraño es que en mi móvil (versión debug nueva) tampoco me deja instalar las versiones firmadas pero si borro la de debug si puedo instalar una sobre otra las versiones firmadas sin problemas

Comment: Agrega detalles a tu pregunta, que versionCode tienen las apps?, fueron firmadas con el mismo certificado? Lo que comentas que se muestra un símbolo de exclamación sucede por varias causas. Revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: La anterior versión era de otro programador. La versionCode en teoría no la he cambiado. La versionName si. Con el mismo certificado no porque he creado el diccionario de keys, Lo extraño es que en mi móvil (versión debug nueva) tampoco me deja instalar las versiones firmadas pero si borro la de debug si puedo instalar una sobre otra las versiones firmadas sin problemas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente pude instalar la nueva versión firmando la app con las keys del anterior programador y cambiando la versionCode como bien apuntabais

Comment: Es lo que comentaba en mi respuesta, debes asegurar firmar la app con el mismo certificado, recuerda que si alguna respuesta te ayudo a resolver la problematica planteada en la pregunta puedes marcarla como soluciòn, revisa [tour], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Comentas que

> "La versionCode en teoría no la he cambiado. La versionName si"

**una de las causas por la cual no puedes instalar es precisamente que intentes instalar una aplicación con el mismo `versionCode` que la aplicación instalada, la nueva aplicación debe tener un `versionCode` mayor.**

El `versionName` no es tan importante ya que es solo una descripción e incluso puedes dejar el mismo valor.

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
  }
  ...
}
```

[versionCode](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning?hl=es-419#appversioning): Es el valor entero positivo que se usa como número de versión interna. Solo se utiliza para determinar si una versión es más reciente que otra; los números más altos indican versiones más recientes. Este no es el número de versión que se muestra a los usuarios, que se establece a través de la configuración versionName a continuación. El sistema Android usa el valor `versionCode` para evitar que la app cambie a una versión inferior, ya que no permite que los usuarios instalen un APK con un `versionCode` menor que el de la versión instalada actualmente en su dispositivo.

**Si tienes una aplicación instalada la nueva aplicación que será la actualización debe ser firmada con el mismo certificado.**